# How owerride entity node delete core function

Tags: database, hooks

I'm doing a headless drupal cms.

I need to check the entities before they are deleted.
I need to do it globally as the deletion of entities can take place via api (already written) or by using the cms as an administrator.

How can I overwrite the "delete" core operation?
I've tried using hooks (hook_entity_predelete / hook_entity_delete) but they don't block delete operation.
I need something like this:

```
if ($condition == true) 
  core_delete()
else
  disable_core_delete()
```

Thank you

Comment: I might be wrong, but I think you'll have to do this on a type-by-type basis. It would be something similar to https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/281940/alter-users-entity-label-method/281941#281941 but overriding the `delete` method instead. You'd need a class per entity type for that solution

Comment: You can block deletion in an entity hook by throwing an exception. To avoid a generic 500 error catch this exception in an exception subscriber and return a json response containing a more specific error message.

Comment: See https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/235602/how-do-handle-exceptions

Answer (score 1):

The only way I can think to do this is to override the entity's storage handler in hook_entity_type_alter() with a storage handler that provides the delete functionality you want.

Something like

```
// You're going to want to be sure you're extending the entity's original
// storage handler.
class CustomStorageHandler extends EntityStorageBase {

  /*
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function delete(array $entities) {
    array_filter($entities, function ($entity) {
      // Do your logic to determine if the entity should be deleted here.
      // This example only allows entities with odd ids to be deleted.
      return (bool) $entity_id % 2;
    }
    parent::delete($entities)
  } 
}
```

It is probably a better idea, however, to use the entity's access system to prevent users from deleting entities as it will be confusing to try to delete an entity, then for that to not happen.